# C++ - Find adjacent elements in std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary

What is the most efficient way to look up the adjacent elements in a STL map using the examples I mention below:

Suppose I have a map of integer - string:

```
1 -> Test1
5 -> Test2
10 -> Test3
20 -> Test4
50 -> Test5
```

If I call:

```
get_adjacent(1) // Returns iterator to 1 and 5
get_adjacent(2) // Returns iterator to 1 and 5
get_adjacent(24) // Returns iterator to  20 and 50
get_adjacent(50) // Returns iterator to 20 and 50
```

Comment: I don't think `std::map` is necessarily the right thing to use if you want to do this. Take a look at some std algorithms: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: Adjacency makes no sense for a map.

Comment: From your examples, it is still unclear what you mean by "adjacent". Can you describe what this means?

Comment: If you wanted a cooked answer, it would be wise for you to include actual code, so we don't have to make up context. This is why I stop at the detail level I currently provide. /cc @Xeo

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` for exactly this.

Better yet `std::map::equal_range` combines the power of both:

See it live on http://liveworkspace.org/code/d3a5eb4ec726ae3b5236b497d81dcf27

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

const auto data = std::map<int, std::string> {
    { 1  , "Test1" }, 
        { 5  , "Test2" }, 
        { 10 , "Test3" }, 
        { 20 , "Test4" }, 
        { 50 , "Test5" }, 
};

template <typename Map, typename It>
void debug_print(Map const& map, It it)
{
    if (it != map.end())
        std::cout << it->first;
    else
        std::cout << "[end]";
}

void test(int key)
{
    auto bounds = data.equal_range(key);

    std::cout << key << ": " ; debug_print(data, bounds.first)  ; 
    std::cout << ", "        ; debug_print(data, bounds.second) ; 
    std::cout << '\n'        ; 
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    test(1);
    test(2);
    test(24);
    test(50);
}
```

Outputs:

```
1: 1, 5
2: 5, 5
24: 50, 50
50: 50, [end]
```

Comment: First, use the map members, second use `equal_range` which is `[lower_bound(), upper_bound()]`.

Comment: @Xeo that's exactly what I just posted. Took me some time to get useful demo output for the iterators :)

Comment: Note that `test(2)` should be `1, 5` not `5, 5` and `test(24)` and `test(50)` should be `20, 50`.

Comment: @Xeo I'm just showing the standard facilities here. I figure the OP can extrapolate it from here - the rest is rather pedestrian (a bit of [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) and boundary checking should do). I choose to stop here, as chances are that this solves the issue already by virtue of the usual [XY component](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `map::lower_bound` will return the first element that does not evaluate less than the key (see [map::lower_bound description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound/)), which implies that if you ask for `test(0.5)` you will receive the interval from 1 to 5.

Comment: @Tryskele As you'll note, my implementation doesn't use lower_bound in this fashion. Also, you can trivially check that it **doesn't** return an interval [1,5]. Instead, it correctly returns an empty interval ([1,1]) which is easy to detect in case you wanted to do input validation: [demonstration](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3mrPRV$1)